# How to synchronize Nodejs functions

Tags: javascript, node.js, sqlite

I am working on a NodeJs server and I am implementing a `Sqlite3` database.

My problem is that the "saveMddToDb" method starts before the "createMddTables" method is finished.

So I would like to know how to wait until the end of the first one before starting the second one.

```
const db = require('./db.js');

const myDb = new db(configServer.dataBase.useDatabase === true ? configServer.dataBase.name : null);
myDb.createMddTables();
myDb.saveMddToDb(dataModel);
```

```
class Db {
  constructor(name) {
    this.db = new sqlite3.Database(name === null ? ':memory:' : name, err => {
      if (err) {
        return console.error(err.message);
      }
      console.log(colors.yellow(`Connected to the ${name === null ? 'memory' : name} SQlite database`));
    });
  }

  close() {
    this.db.close(err => {
      if (err) {
        return console.error(err.message);
      }
      console.log(colors.yellow('Close the database connection'));
    });
  };

  createMddTables() {
    this.createTableContacts();
  };

  createTableContacts() {
    const sql = `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS contacts (
      id TEXT PRIMARY KEY,
      firstName TEXT NOT NULL,
      lastName TEXT NOT NULL,
      nickName TEXT NOT NULL,
      profilePicture BLOB)`;

    this.db.run(sql, err => {
      if (err) {
        return console.log(err.message);
      }
      console.log(colors.yellow('Table contacts created'));
    });
  };

  saveMddToDb(mddJson) {
    if(mddJson) {
      const sqlContacts = `INSERT OR IGNORE INTO contacts VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)`;

      mddJson.contacts.forEach(contact => {
        this.db.run(sqlContacts, [uuidv4(), contact.firstName, contact.lastName, contact.lastName, contact.profilePicture], err => {
            if (err) {
              return console.log(err.message);
            }
            console.log(colors.yellow('Contacts added to database'));
          });
      });
    }
  }

};

module.exports = Db;
```

Comment: Can you tell us which `sqlite3` package you are using? This would be helpful to provide you more information whether it is promise based or callback based.

Comment: I use sqlite3 4.1.0

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by using [Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise). Also, as suggested before, you can use [async/await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function), which is syntactic sugar for Promises, so you can write your code like synchronous code.

An async/await function always returns a Promise, so before using it I'd recommend you look up Promises first, and try to write your code with them. As soon as that works, you can rewrite it using async/await, so you know you fully understand what you're using and why it works!

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `async/await` for that see [here](https://javascript.info/async-await)

here is the example

```
async function fun1(req, res){
  let response = await request.get('http://localhost:3000');
    if (response.err) { console.log('error');}
    else { console.log('fetched response');
}
```